# Disable local git repository in Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

In previous versions of Xcode there used to be a checkbox when creating a new project, which would toggle creating a local git repository.

This seems to be gone in the latest version. I'm running 4.6.1, though it may have been removed in 4.6.

I use another source control (Subversion), so all these extra git files can be annoying. I know how to remove the .git folder and remove the git repository, but is there any way to prevent Xcode automatically creating it in the first place?

Comment: My xcode is also 4.6.1, but I can see the checkbox to choice whether create local git repo.

Comment: I do have a checkbox too. I'm also running Xcode 4.6.1. The checkbox is at the bottom of the _choose path_ dialog which appears _after_ you choose a name for your new project.

Comment: Aha - either it's moved recently, or I just have a bad memory. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox is present in Xcode 4.6.1. It is at the bottom of the *choose path* dialog which appears *after* you choose a name for your new project.

The label says:

```
Source Control: Create local git repository for this project
                Xcode will place your project under version control
```